# TKinter not working on ARM

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, arm

i have compiled python 2.6.6 for arm , and its working on arm . but when i import tkinter i am getting below error.

```
import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_tkinter.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

am i doing anything wrong here ? or do i need to do something else.
My host is not using x11, instead eglfs does that have any impact here ?

Thanks
brijesh

Comment: to create the cross compile i followed http://randomsplat.com/id5-cross-compiling-python-for-embedded-linux.html

Comment: have you installed/compiled the tk/tcl libraries and headers? have a look at the output of python's `./configure`, is it complaining about missing libraries?